# Body-swap TV movie wherein sexual assault victim victimises her male attacker in her own body?

Tags: story-identification

Around 1995-2000 I saw a late-night TV movie on the Sci-Fi Channel, I think. The central plot involved a man who forced himself upon a woman and the turnabout when they somehow swapped bodies. The climax involved an edgy revenge where the initial victim used her attacker's body to terrify, overpower, and rape him in her own body.

Can you identify this film? Thank you.

Comment: The premise sounds similar to a story written by jean Marie Stine (aka Hank Stine); called Season of the Witch, written in 1968. The main character rapes and murders a woman. He is sentenced to have his consciousness placed in her body. The book was made into a film called Memory Run in 1995, but the film altered the story, making it even less like your question.

Comment: Not quite the same thing, but *Salvage* has a similar theme with a murder-rape victim seemingly reliving her death and rape over and over again, but with the reveal that it was actually her murderer reliving her end.

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/236272/fantasy-movie-which-is-a-collection-of-stories-with-music-theme

Answer (score 3):

It's from the 2001 TV show **[Strange Frequency](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0289828/)**, specifically the episode *Instant Karma* that also appeared in **[Strange Frequency 2](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0475404/)**.  From [IMDB](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0475404/plotsummary):

> Innocent Lara idolizes bad-boy rock star Vince Brava and is convinced that they are soul mates. When she's tapped to join other groupies on his tour bus after a concert, she's delighted at the chance to show Vince how much they have in common. After Vince takes advantage of her innocence, however, she's determined to get revenge;but when she and Vince swap bodies, her vengeance is far more appropriate even than she had planned.

Comment: Please add some quotes and/or description supporting your answer.

Comment: This answer is quite sparse and low-quality, can you please add some more details and especially address the parts the match the OP's criteria.