# Fantasy movie which is a collection of stories with "music" theme

Tags: story-identification, movie

I remember watching this movie around 2004 on Canal+ (I think it aired in at least two parts). It was a collection of short fantasy films (stories). Each story was about 20-30 minutes long and it had completely separate plot to other stories. Every one of them had a theme related to music, have supernatural elements and ends badly for main character.

The stories I remember:

- A story about a politician who had a car accident in which his wife died. When he listens to a specific song, he goes back in time to that accident (like in the movie "Butterfly Effect") and is able to change things in the past, save his wife and do do other things to help himself get a better career. At the end he messes things up and ends up deaf, unable to hear that song and fix it.
- A story about musician who sells his soul to the devil to be the best guitar player in the world. The devil gives him that, and the guy has an amazing career. After some time, the devil comes back to collect his soul, but the guy doesn't want to go to hell. So the devil offers him a challenge - he gives him a sheet with music and tells him that if he is able to play that perfectly, then he will win and can keep his soul. The musician agrees and began playing.

  As he does, the string on his guitar breaks and his finger is bleeding. Drops of blood fall on that sheet and make additional notes that he now has to play. He keeps bleeding, new notes appear, other strings break. At the end when he is finished, one last drop of blood creates​ a sign that means "play everything one more time". He can't and loses the bet. Devil comments, that Hendrix wasn't able to do that either. I think this story was called "Coda".
- A story about a guy who takes drugs to write songs. His band doesn't want him to take more drugs and want to kick him out. He ends up locked in the mental hospital in the end, where lots of songs writers are. I think there was someone evil using them to make hit songs, but I can't remember.
- A story about music store. There was something about vinyl records, but I can't remember what.

I think this movie was in two parts, 4 stories per part. Or maybe those were two separate movies in a series.

Comment: Live action or animated?

Comment: It was live action.

Comment: Jimmi Hendrix is not in hell, but in the other place. Just sayin'...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*Strange Frequency 2* (2002).

From [IMDb](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0475404/plotsummary?ref_=tt_ov_pl) (formatting mine):

> "Soul Man"
> Soft-spoken guitar tuner and roadie Mitch longs to be a guitar player and to have some of the perks of the obnoxious guitar idol he works for, like his pretty, neglected girlfriend. **But his luck doesn't turn until he finds a curiosity at a junk shop-sheet music for what is supposedly Jimi Hendrix's last song. Although the aging beatnik who runs the shop warns him that playing the music will summon up the devil, Mitch buys it anyway.** When he plays it, he suddenly finds his fortunes improving, thanks in part to the efforts of a new manager, sleek Simon Rathbone. But-surprise, surprise-it isn't all roses from here on out.
>
> **"Cold Turkey"**
> **Singer, songwriter, and recovering addict Jared is trying to get his act together before his band starts a new tour, but he's finding it hard to write new songs without chemical assistance.** Enter an alluring blond, who leads him back to the bottle and into trouble even as she helps him find inspiration again. But who is she, really? (Don't read the cover blurb, or you'll find out way too soon.)
>
> "Instant Karma"
> Innocent Lara idolizes bad-boy rock star Vince Brava and is convinced that they are soul mates. When she's tapped to join other groupies on his tour bus after a concert, she's delighted at the chance to show Vince how much they have in common. After Vince takes advantage of her innocence, however, she's determined to get revenge;but when she and Vince swap bodies, her vengeance is far more appropriate even than she had planned.
>
> **"Don't Stop Believin'"**
> **Senatorial candidate Ben Stanton is on the brink of losing the election, to the disgust of his ambitious wife. Ever since he was involved in a car accident in which his young mistress was killed, he's been trailing in the polls. But listening to the CD she made him of his campaign song suddenly takes him back to the moments before the accident. Maybe this time he can change the course of events.**

---

Found with the Google query `film guitar pact devil blood music sheet site:imdb.com/title`.

Comment: That's the movie! Thank you!